# SQL query that joins two tables and returns multiple matches from one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, concatenation

My title is terrible, and that's probably why I'm not finding what I want on Google.

What I'm trying to do is export some data from an old in-house blog so I can import it into something else.  My issue is that while I can kind of create the sort of JOIN I'm looking for, the match in the second table can contain multiple rows, so I end up with tons of duplicate data.  I need to take the results from the second table and concat those (if there are multiple matches) into a single field in the query result.  There is no need for a WHERE constraint on the query, I'm trying to retrieve the entire blog_posts table.

Hopefully this abbreviated layout of the table structure will help illustrate:

```
blog_posts              blog_categories
---------------------------------------
post_id                 post_id
post_content            category_id
post_author
```

And here's some sample data.

blog_posts table data:

```
post_id  post_content  post_author
----------------------------------
1        foo1          bob
2        foo2          bob
3        foo3          fred
```

blog_categories table data:

```
post_id  category_id
--------------------
1        1
1        2
1        6
2        1
3        2
3        4
```

And what my ideal results would look like would be this:

```
post_id  post_content  post_author  category_ids
------------------------------------------------
1        foo1          bob          1,2,6
2        foo2          bob          1
3        foo3          fred         2,4
```

The closest I could get was a simple join like this:

```
SELECT 
    blog_posts.post_id, 
    blog_posts.post_content, 
    blog_posts.post_author, 
    blog_categories.category_id 
FROM blog_posts 
    INNER JOIN blog_categories 
        ON blog_posts.post_id = blog_categories.post_id
```

But that returns matches in the blog_posts table multiple times (one time for each category_id that matches).

Is there any way to accomplish what I want using just SQL?  I'm thinking some sort of sub-select would work, but what I can't wrap my head around how that would work - I know I'd essentially want to do a select in my "loop" for the category ids using the current post id, but the syntax for that escapes me.  It need not be efficient, this is a one-time operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function does exactly what you need:

```
SELECT 
  blog_posts.post_id, 
  blog_posts.post_content, 
  blog_posts.post_author, 
  group_concat(blog_categories.category_id)
FROM blog_posts 
JOIN blog_categories ON blog_posts.post_id = blog_categories.post_id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: @BenjaminM YEs - it's a mysql only function, but the question is mysql

Comment: the question is mysql since i made it mysql ;)

Comment: I'm looking at this, and while the BLOB output is giving me issues with the export, it seems to work.  I don't understand how it works in the slightest though, particularly the "GROUP BY" at the end.  Are those category_id's or post_id's?  I have around 420 post_id rows and 40 category_id rows - I'm hoping my "GROUP BY" doesn't actually need to list every one of those.

Comment: Further, if I use `GROUP BY blog_posts.post_id, blog_posts.post_content, blog_posts.post_author` at the end of the query, it certainly seems to work.  I spot-checked some data and it looks good.  Even added another JOIN so that I can pull category names from yet another table.

Comment: @sporker the SQL standard allows grouped columns to be referenced by their *position* instead of their expession. This is particularly handy when the column us a long calculation, but I find the brevity pleasing. Done shun this syntax, but I embrace it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `GROUP BY blog_posts.post_id, blog_posts.post_content, blog_posts.post_author`. And then use an `aggregate function` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) to take ALL the `blog_categories.category_id` values from each group and turn it into a single string.

Which DBMS are you using? For Postgres you could probably simply use an array as aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  blog_posts.post_id,
  blog_posts.post_content,
  blog_posts.post_author,
  ARRAY_AGG(blog_categories.category_id)
FROM blog_posts
INNER JOIN blog_categories ON blog_posts.post_id = blog_categories.post_id
GROUP BY
  blog_posts.post_id,
  blog_posts.post_content,
  blog_posts.post_author
```

Or use `ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(blog_categories.category_id), ',')` to get a comma separated string.

Comment: Just for the record, this is MySQL.

Comment: Sorry.  On the upside though, I work with PostgreSQL more often than MySQL, so I've added your answer to my local list of notes.